# npm install after run the playwright image for docker getting below error

Tags: playwright, playwright-test

npm ERR! Tracker "idealTree" already exists

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-11-19T05_41_58_533Z-debug-0.log

I am setting up docker to execute playwright test